# PreferencesActivity can't setChecked() on checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, preferenceactivity

I have 1 PreferenceActivity

in preferences.xml is

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/pushCB"
        android:checked="true"
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="PushService"
        android:summary="Set to enable push service for ..."
        android:title="Use Push Service" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
```

and in PreferenceActivity i have

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    final CheckBox pushServiceCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pushCB);
    pushServiceCB.setChecked(Dynamic_Value);
}
```

but nothing happen. Why? and how can i fix this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `final CheckBoxPreference pushServiceCB = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference ("PushService");`to get that object.

Comment: thanks a lot. now it's work great. I wasted my time half a day for did this.